# Integrating Jenkins with Gitlab

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I need to setup a build configuration in Jenkins so that whenever a build is triggered, I get my latest scripts from Gitlab and copy them to the target systems and run that script on the target.

I couldn't find any relevant info for integrating Gitlab to Jenkins. Are there any specific plugins that I could use?

I am using Jenkins version 2.158

Comment: Hi. Do you know about devops, webhooks?

Comment: no i have no idea

Answer (score 0):

Step by Step procedure for doing what you are looking for:

1. Add the location of the Script from GitLAB. (E.g.)
   [image]
2. Run the script over the target machine.

While Building the job, you will get the code at the root (./) of the job's workspace. Copying and running the script over the target machine can be done by remote script executions. following are the cases we having in running script in the remote machine

1. Windows (jenkins) to windows - use [psexec.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)
2. Windows (Jenkins) to linux - use [plink.exe](https://superuser.com/a/1340922/590517) which is command line putty
3. Linux (Jenkins) to linux - use [SCP](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-scp-command-to-securely-transfer-files/) and [SSH](https://www.cnet.com/news/ssh-tip-send-commands-remotely/)
4. Linux to Windows - use [ansible for windows](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/blob/master/windows/run-powershell.yml).

E.g,.

```
$ scp script.sh remote_username@10.10.0.2:/remote/directory
$ ssh -t remote_username@10.10.0.2 /remote/directory/script.sh
```

All the best.

Comment: Thanks but ,when i gave my gitab repository url i was getting an error  **Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git.exe ls-remote -h https://gitlab.company.net/user.name/project_name HEAD**

Answer (score 0):

Integration between **Git Repository Management** (github, gitlab,bitbucket, etc) and **Jenkins** has the following steps :

- Developer push some source code (java, php, nodejs, etc) to the Git Repository Management.
- The Git Repository Management detects this event and **notify** to some **public** http endpoint in your Jenkins. Currently **webhook** is the most recommended way to implement this notification.
- Jenkins receive the http post request(from bitbucket for example) and using some plugin or configurations , Jenkins try to determine or get the basic devops parameters like : branch name, commit author, commit message, technology, etc
- Whit the extracted devops parameters, Jenkins launchs a preconfigured job. This job use the previously extracted values to build, compile, zip, install or to do whatever is necessary to startup your application.

If you want to implement this flow, check this post:

https://jrichardsz.github.io/devops/devops-with-git-and-jenkins-using-webhooks

Also, if you need. I will gladly to show you a basic integration using some git repository management and jenkins . Just contact me.