# How deploy source code as an application in a linux virtual machine on Azure using Jenkins?

Tags: git, azure, jenkins, virtual-machine, jenkins-plugins

I've installed it and I've set the path (C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe). i've also tried this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/sl-si/azure/jenkins/install-jenkins-solution-template but it also gives me this console output.

I've installed it, I've set the git path, I still get this. I've been stuck here for a couple days, every build I make gives me a similar error message.
i use a windows 10 computer, and i have a linux VM on azure.

The Free Swap Space on my on the azure node in jenkins says its on 0B, but there is 26,99GB of Free Temp Space. Is maybie that the problem?

Anyway this is my console output for the tutorial i've completed:

```
Started by user admin
Building remotely on testadminjenkinsazure115f10 (ubuntu) in workspace /home/Jenkinsadmin/workspace/mySampleApp
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
[WS-CLEANUP] Deferred wipeout is used...
[WS-CLEANUP] Done
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe init /home/Jenkinsadmin/workspace/mySampleApp # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not init /home/Jenkinsadmin/workspace/mySampleApp
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:787)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:579)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:212)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to testadminjenkinsazure115f10
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1741)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:357)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:955)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor870.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:132)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy222.execute(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1146)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1186)
        at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1208)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
        at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1810)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing command: C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe init /home/Jenkinsadmin/workspace/mySampleApp
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2023)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1984)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1980)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1612)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:785)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" (in directory "/home/Jenkinsadmin/workspace/mySampleApp"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:249)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:218)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:936)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:455)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2012)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 20 more
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Welcome to S.O!! Are you using windows to develop and Linux for Jenkins? Is this log from Jenkins job build ?

Comment: I am using a windows 10 machine for jenkins and a linux (ubuntu) virtual machine on Azure. Yeah, i want to build a job on the virtual machine on azure.

Comment: Is your current approach a proof of concept ?  In a real software environment you will need at least :  #1 developer machine #2 server for  your Jenkins (linux for heaven's sake) and #3 Some server for your application deployment. Developer just push code to git , Jenkins is notified of this event , triggering the build of pre-configured job on the remote application server.

Comment: Getting back to the initial question. #1 Do you have a git repository with source code of some application (java, ruby, python, etc)? # Do you need to deploy this source code as an application in your  linux (ubuntu) virtual machine on Azure using your local Jenkins ( windows 10 ) ?

Comment: Yes, I need to deploy the source code in a virtual machine on Azure, and I want to use my local Jenkins. As you can see I am doing this for the first time. Do you maybe have a tutorial I could follow? thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Your Jenkins is already configured in your local windows-10 but you show us a link to **Create a Jenkins server on an Azure Linux VM from the Azure portal**.  I think you are a little confused.

My advice related to a basic infrastructure on your Azure is:

- Have a Jenkins in a linux machine on azure
- According to your programming language, configure **another** linux machine on azure (if you are not using .net).
- Use github, gitlab or bitbucket as repository to your source code.

From your windows 10, you just need to push changes using git.

My advice related to a basic integration between Jenkins, source code repository and your application server, could be:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53835514/3957754

Nowadays the previous flow or integration is common. Of course, exist more complex approaches like : kubernetes, ansible, artifact repository, jenkinsX, etc or saas providers with minimal configurations like : jelastic, heroku, openshift,etc

Answer (score 0):

From your info and log, I see that you've configured master Jenkins on your Windows computer, but trying to run the job remotely on Ubuntu agent:

`Building remotely on testadminjenkinsazure115f10 (ubuntu) in workspace /home/Jenkinsadmin/workspace/mySampleApp`

So, you need to install Git on your Ubuntu VM. As [JRichardsz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3957754/jrichardsz) already said, from Windows you just need to push changes to Git server.