# Which option will be the best to integrate gitlab with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, gitlab-ci

Currently, I am using a Jenkins file for my pipeline.

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.EnvVars
@Library('pipeline-library')_

stage('Tag SVN') {
  node('build01') {
    if ("${env.TagBuild}" == 'true'){
       bat 'svn copy -r HEAD %RepoURL% %RepoTagsURL%/%RepoTagName% -m "Tagging at Revision"'
    }
  }
}

stage('Checkout') {
  node('build01') {
    if ("${env.Build_APP}" == 'true') {
      ws('c:\\Dev') {
        svnCheckout('${RepoURL}')
      }
    }
  }

}

stage('Build and Import DAR') {
  node('build01') {
    if ("${env.Build_APP}" == 'true') {
      visBuild3("C:\\Dev\\scripts\\Component.bld")
    }
    
  }
}

stage('Deploy') {  
    node('build01') {
    if ("${env.Build_Common}" == 'true') {
    script {
                    env.buildNumber = "${TagVersion}.Build${env.BUILD_NUMBER}_${ComponentTagName}"
                    env.packageid = "Applications/common/${env.buildNumber}"
             
                }
      xldDeploy serverCredentials: 'username', environmentId: 'Environments/AWS/Dev_Test_Envs/SysTest1/SysTest1_WildFly', packageId: env.packageid
    }
    }
  }  
}
```

It is working perfectly. Currently, I am using groovy to checkout code from SVN.

```
svnCheckout('${RepoURL}')
```

But I want to make this working for Gitlab. I have gone through a lot of documentation but everywhere they have integrated for freestyle project, not for the pipeline as code.

I found this document a little bit helpful but It confused me with so many options.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#global-plugin-configuration

I am looking to start with the simple flow I want to trigger a build whenever I do commit on the Git project and get the status of the Jenkins build. Where can I start in order to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**First:** You can integrate Jenkins and any source code management (bitbucket, github,gitlab,etc) with whatever you want: free style project, pipeline script or declarative pipeline.

Related to **trigger a build whenever a git event is performed**,  you need to read  or research about **webhooks**.

This answer could help you to understand what is webhook and how implement a basic flow:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53835514/3957754